# Would a graviton if it exists have energy?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, quantum-gravity

If it has energy and comes from all matter would then matter lose mass as it releases these gravitons that have energy given that energy and mass can be converted to each other?

Comment: Have you applied your question to real photons coupling to charged matter? To virtual photons coupling to charged matter?

Comment: I have not,  I only have high school physics background but was reading some layman stuff about quantum mechanics and it got me wondering about things.  I was wondering mainly if all matter loses tiny tiny amounts of mass over time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, massless gravitons would have energy and momentum, just like massless photons and massless gluons.

Matter radiates gravitons when it accelerates in certain ways, such as two stars orbiting around each other. The energy radiated in the gravitons typically simply reduces the sum of the kinetic energy and the gravitational potential energy of the radiating objects.

Comment: that sounds like gravitational waves, they also reduce the kinetic energy of the orbiting objects

Comment: @Yukterez Yes. The relationship between gravitons and gravitational waves is essentially the same as the relationship between photons and electromagnetic waves.

Comment: so gravitational waves are real gravitons, and the regular gravitational field of a body is virtual gravitons then?

Comment: @Yukterez That's my understanding.

Comment: Would the matter emitting the gravitons lose mass ?

Comment: No. In the case of orbiting stars, the mass of each star doesn’t change. Their kinetic energy and their gravitational potential energy changes. This means that the mass *of the binary system* changes, but the mass of the constituents does not.

Comment: Suppose we take a much simpler case of the scattering of one electron by another electron. This interaction theoretically creates gravitons, but it does not change the mass of an electron. In mainstream physics, elementary particles have fixed masses (unless the Higgs field changes its value).